# Using Entity Framework how can i find out when the last change was made to a table?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a quick way to find out when last change took place in some table?

**EDIT:**

I realize that i can add a column which will hold a change date, but i am wondering if there is some kind of metadata that can be accessed by EF. My db is hosted on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. If you are aware that you can add a "ModifiedDate" column to your entity, then why do I get that felling that you'd rather not go that route? Are there some type of constraints (not the DB kind) at play here that prevent you from going the easier route?

Comment: 2 Jason: yes i do have constraints - it is my dba :) and i was just wondering if it is possible to do that without adding columns to db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a 'last updated' column to your table and query that one for the latest change.

**Update:** If that is not an option as per the update to the question, you could:
a) create a separate db table with table name and date/time and update that one with triggers on the table you want to track.
...or...
b) since you're using SQL Server 2008 you could possibly do something with [SQL Server change tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx). There's no built-in support for change tracking in EF, but that doesn't prevent you from using it 'on the side'...

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly an option, but it is a least one in my situation. I will update my question.

Comment: this information is not available in raw sql -- it certainly won't available in EF.