# EF Core: How to create a service that will detect external changes (new records) in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, .net-core, quartz

I'm using .Net Core with EF and the problem I want to solve is:

How to auto-detect DB's latest record changed and if yes, then run my function.

I don't want to send a query to my DB every e.g 10 seconds or 1 minute to search for changes, because it would kill my server (a lot of data is added every second). I don't want to use `Quartz` also.

Are there any mechanisms that would auto-run something if something has changed (new record in table was created)?

Comment: Knowing which database would probably help.

Comment: It is not practical when a database is shared and can have hundreds of transactions a second.  The best is to use a database that is designed as multi-user.

Comment: It depend on DBMS. Look at [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

According to @KristoferA answer from:
[Using Entity Framework how can i find out when the last change was made to a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120602/using-entity-framework-how-can-i-find-out-when-the-last-change-was-made-to-a-tab)

There is no built-in support for change tracking in EF.

Besides quartz there are also other options like a loop with Thread.Sleep in a new thread that checks if a new row with specific 'createdAt' / 'updatedAt' or 'modifiedAt' column was added..

You could then maybe raise an event and call your function that something got updated?

It depends on what you want to do.